# Vue 3 router with Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am new to Vue JS and I installed vue 3 with laravel and it shows `404 Not Found`. I tried a lot but could not find out the issue.

*app.blade.php*

```
<div class="min-h-screen bg-gray-100" id="app">           

            <!-- Page Content -->
            <main>
                {{ $slot }}
            </main>
 </div>
```

*app.js*

```
import { createApp } from "vue";
import router from './router'
import CompaniesIndex from './components/companies/CompaniesIndex'

createApp({
    components: {
        CompaniesIndex
    }
}).use(router).mount('#app')
```

*index.js*

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from "vue-router";

import CompaniesIndex from '../components/companies/CompaniesIndex' 
const routes = [
    {
        path: '/welcome',
        name: 'companies.index',
        component: CompaniesIndex
    },
    
]

export default createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(),
    routes
})
```

*ComponiesIndex.vue*

```
<template>
Hello world
</template>

<script>
export default {
    
}
</script>
```

*web.php*

```
Route::get('/{any}', function () { return view('app'); })->where('any', '. *');
```

*welcome.blade.php*

```
<body class="antialiased">
         <h1>Welcome to Laravel Vue 3</h1>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. I'm not sure, but there is maybe an error in your `routes/web.php` in `where` statement, because `. *` regex should match any string and this is `.*` without whitespace. Please try:

   ```php
   Route::view('/{any}', 'app')->where('any', '.*');
   ```
2. If you are creating SPA your `app.blade.php` should not contain any markup, it should be blank HTML template with required script with your app:

   ```php
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
   <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

        <script src="{{ mix('assets/js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
        <link href="{{ mix('assets/css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
   </head>
   <body>
        <noscript>
            <strong>We're sorry but this app doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong>
        </noscript>
        <div id="app"></div>
   </body>
   </html>
   ```
3. Then you just mount your Vue app to `#app` div, which seems to be good in your `app.js`.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I did the same as you mentioned but now it's showing a blank page.

Comment: This means it works. Try to go to `/welcome`, you should end up having `Hello world` from your `ComponiesIndex.vue`. If there is still nothing - check paths to your scripts in `mix('assets/js/app.js')`

Comment: W8. You actually don't have root component. Please check some vue examples, there are to much to describe: https://github.com/gothinkster/vue-realworld-example-app/tree/master/src

Comment: still, it shows the blank page. it's the index.js import Vue from "vue";
import Router from "vue-router";

Vue.use(Router);

export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
     
    path: '/welcome',
       name: 'companies.index',
         component: CompaniesIndex
    }, 
  ]
});

Comment: In the console it shows No match found for the location with path "/welcome"

Comment: I am having same problem, do you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel my-blog


1)  npm install

2)  npm install vue-loader@next vue@next vue-router@next

3)  npm install @vitejs/plugin-vue --save-dev


4)  npm run dev

5)  vite.config.js
    
    import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'


    .....
    
    plugins: [
        
        laravel({
        
            input:['resources/css/app.css', 'resourcesd/js/app.js'],
            
            refresh: true,
    
            }),
    
        vue()
        
        ],


6)  create folder components

7)  in folder components create app.vue

    <template>
        <h1> Hello! im app.vue</h1>
    </template>

8)  in app.js

    import { createApp } from 'vue'

    import app from './components/app.vue'

    createApp(app).mount("#app")

9)   in view welcome destroy body and add:
    
    <div id="app"></div>
    
    in head:    @vite(['resource/js/app.js', 'resources/css/app.css'])


10) test site

11) in dir components create dir pages in dir pages create components index.vue and about.vue


    <template>
        <h1>Im index page</h1>
    </template>

    <template>
        <h1>Im about page</h1>
    </template>





13) in dir components create component NotFound

    <template>
        <h1>Not Found</h1>
    </template>








14) create dir router in dir components і в ній файл index
    
    import {createRouter, createWebHistory } from "vue-router";

    import pageIndex from '../components/pages/index.vue'

    import pageAbout from '../components/pages/about.vue'
    
    const routes = [
        
        {
    
            path:   '/',
    
            component: pageIndex
        },
        {
            path: '/:pathMatch(.*)*',
            
            component: notFound
        }
    ]

    const router = createRouter({

        history: createWebHistory(),
        
        routes

    })

    export default router




15)     in wep.php

    Route::get('/', function() {

        return view('welcome');
    });

    Route::get('/{pathMatch}', function (){
    
       return view('welcome');
    
    })->where('pathMatch',".*");







16)     in app.vue


    <template>
        <router-view/>
    </template>

17) edit app.js

    import router from './components/router/index.js'
    
    createApp(app).use(router).mount("#app')

18) test site

19) in component notFound 

    <router-link to = "/">index</router-link>   

    <router-link to = "/about">about</router-link>

20) test site
```

more look in this [Laravel 10 Vue 3 Router](https://youtu.be/GzS5dqTFdsY?si=RGkCMK8Yg0VEPrkV)

Comment: This is code formatted, but I doubt it is all code. Please check https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting and [answer]. Please also add some explanation of the effect of each step and why the whole sequence helps to solve the problem.