# How to use Vue router inside of Laravel?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-router4

I develop with laravel9 and vue3.

My problem is simple, But path setting is not go well.

When I access url `localhost:8080/tasks`

This url return 404 not found and I get the following type error

> GET http://localhost:8000/tasks 404 (Not Found)

I didn't know the reason , but When I rewrite path: `/tasks` to path `/`, localhost:8080 return Component that I want to need.

I have following files.

`router.js`

```js
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from "vue-router";
import TaskListComponent from "./components/TaskListComponent.vue";


const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(),
    routes: [

        {
            path: '/tasks',
            name: 'tasks.list',
            component: TaskListComponent
        }
    ]
})

export default router
```

`App.vue`

```html
<script setup>
import HeaderComponent from "./components/HeaderComponent.vue";
</script>

<template>
    <HeaderComponent />
    <router-view></router-view>
</template>
```

`bootstrap.js`

```js
import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router.js"

const app = createApp(App);

app.use(router);

app.mount("#app");
```

Comment: Please focus on how to properly highlight your code rather than writing spam in your message.

Comment: I don't have experience with Laravel but this kind of problem can usually be solved by routing all the paths in Laravel to `index.html` and letting Vue do the remaining job

Comment: I found the solution.
add the code below in web.php
Route::get('{any?}', function () {
    return view('welcome');
})->where('any', '.*');

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following in `web.php` fixed the issue

```php
Route::get('{any?}', function () {
    return view('welcome');
})->where('any', '.*');
```

Answer (score 1):

I created a project using [Vue's CLI](https://vuejs.org/guide/quick-start.html#creating-a-vue-application), then proceeded to check all the relevant parts.

I took your code and applied the various changes:

- my entry point is `main.js`, rather than `bootstrap.js` but no changes code-wise
- in `App.vue`, I don't have any `HeaderComponent` but it's should not be an issue anyway
- in `router/index.js`, I only changed the following for the component since it's better to use an alias than a relative path anyway

```js
import TaskListComponent from "@/components/TaskListComponent.vue"
```

Launching the server with

```
pnpm dev
```

gives me some port, once followed to the `/tasks` path, I can see the component as expected.

[image]

The route is properly defined too

[image]

Here is my project directory

[image]

And I don't have any errors in the console.

---

Here is public github repo: https://github.com/kissu/so-v3-working-router

Comment: Thank you so much! but actually, I tried this code in create vue and vue CLI and did well.
I 'm trying with laravel9 and vue3. perhaps, This may happen the problem. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71856260/vue-3-router-with-laravel.
this post is the same problem as mine.
Thank you for going out of your way to implement vue development with my code.

Comment: @sorasakamoto oh, I guess you're using Vue **inside** of Laravel here. I don't know how to debug that one unfortunately since I don't have any experience with Laravel, sorry.